# List<> sorting by object property

Tags: c#, .net, list, object

I need to sort a list of objects by one of the object's properties, but it's a string that needs to be sorted as if it's an integer. The objects are custom "Property" objects where the property name (property.Name) is a string, however 90% of the property names are actually numbers while the other 10% are names/letters (hence while the variable itself has to be a string and not an integer).

I know I can use

```
propertyList.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
```

...but that will sort it looking at it as if it's a string (i.e. 15000 is "greater" than 20).

For sorting purposes, I've already split the list into two separate lists (one that holds all the ones with property names that contain letters and another that contains the ones that can be converted to integers), but I don't know how to sort the "integer" list.

I've tried this and it doesn't work, but is there something like this I can use?

```
propertyList.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Name))
```

Comment: Are you storing the result of `OrderBy(...)`? `OrderBy` does not perform an in-place sort, instead it returns a sorted `IEnumerable<T>` view of your data.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to split the data into two lists; also note that you can perform complex operations inside lambda methods, you just need to use a different syntax:

```
IEnumerable<TItem> sorted = propertyList.OrderBy( x => {
    Int32 asInt;
    if( Int32.TryParse( x.Name, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out asInt ) ) {
        return asInt;
    }
    if( x.Name.Length > 0 ) return (Int32)x.Name[0];
    return 0;
});
```

Note this code is a bit ugly and imperfect as it won't sort two textual names correctly if they start with the same character. I suggest using the more advanced overload of `OrderBy` instead:

```
class NameComparer : IComparer<String> {
    public Int32 Compare(String x, String y) {
        // put Name comparison logic here
    }
}

IEnumerable<TItem> sorted = propertyList.OrderBy( x => x.Name, new NameComparer() );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you actually want here. Do you want an ordered *view* of the original data? Or do you actually want to modify the original data so that it's ordered?

If the former, then the `OrderBy()` method is what you want. It sounds like you're fine sorting the numeric names separately from the non-numeric ones, but in that case it's not clear what you mean by "it doesn't work" when you tried your second code example. That expression should work fine, and would provide an ordered view of your data. E.g.

```
foreach (var x in propertyList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Name))
{
    // do something with the ordered elements
}
```

If you meant that you want to actually order the original data, then you can just use the `List<T>.Sort()` method:

```
propertyList.Sort((x, y) => int.Parse(x.Name).CompareTo(int.Parse(y.Name));
```

Note that in the `List<T>` example, the conversion from string to int is done repeatedly. This should not be a problem for relatively small collections, but if performance becomes an issue then using the LINQ `OrderBy()` method (which caches the keys for you) would be preferred. You can use `ToList()` with `OrderBy()` to materialize the result back to a `List<T>`.

Of course that involves overhead with the intermediate data structures, so there's little point in doing it that way unless you have a genuine demonstrated performance issue to address, *and* you have shown that that alternative fixes the issue.

Comment: `Note that in both of the above examples, the conversion from string to int is done repeatedly`: Not so, `Enumerable.OrderBy` caches the key (these days, at least; it may not always have done so).